# htaccess: Rewrite if url is www.domain.com/some-string/xxx but not www.domain.com/some-string-is-here

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My `htaccess` looks like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^some-string/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^some-string(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

So all requests from www.domain.com/some-string/xxx should be redirected to www.domain.com/xxx (from subfolder to main domain). Now I had the problem that an article contained exactly the `some-string` part in his name e.g. www.domain.com/some-string-is-here. The result is that the article is not found.

How do I have to adapt the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the `RewriteRule` a bit more specific should help; in that case the `RewriteCond` is not necessary. As only requests starting with `some-string/` (including the `/`) should be rewritten, appending that `/` to the rule does the trick for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^some-string/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you also want to rewrite `www.domain.com/some-string` (and only this and not `www.domain.com/some-string-more`), you can try instead:

```
RewriteRule ^some-string(/.*)?$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Now I have `RewriteRule ^some-string/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`. The only problem I have is that if someone types in `www.domain.com/some-string` he is redirected to a wrong page (Wordpress finds some page here). With `www.domain.com/some-string/` it is working as expected.

Comment: The second version with the `^some-string(/.*)?$` should help to rewrite the `www.domain.com/some-string`, too.